# How to renew passport when I can’t reveal my dual nationality

Tags: usa, dual-citizenship

I have a question regarding how to renew a passport in a third part country when I don’t have the right status:

- I have a L1 from Country A and entered the USA on it
- while I’m  in the USA, I want to renew my passport from Country B which is expiring

  - Country B doesn’t allow for dual nationality so I can’t reveal the existence of Passport A

I’m  in the USA and  worried that when I’m  renewing my passport at Embassy B that they’ll ask me what my status in the USA is and I can’t say L1 as that visa is on my Passport A and I can’t say visa waiver or other short term visa as I don’t have the entry stamp AND/OR country B won’t renew passports of people on short stay visas.

[This scenario is based on [another question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/19725/2046) that was clarified to represent a slightly different scenario than this one.]

Comment: Is going to Canada or Mexico as a tourist using passport B, and visiting Embassy B there an option?  If so, Country A and US status might be irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

In these cases, the best thing is to return to Country B and renew your passport  there.

If you’re already planning an extended trip to yet another country, Country D, then you could try renewing it at the consulate there but you’d need to stay in D for a few months for a plausible rationale and your L1 visa status might preclude an extended stay outside the USA.